# Compound nouns ending in past participle verb

Tags: compound-nouns

Why do some compound nouns end in past participle verb, such as: "I'm going to have a 'grammar written' test"?

Comment: It would make more sense to say "written grammar test".

Comment: I agree with BillJ. There is no compond noun there. There is a noun in attributive position that typically comes immediately before the noun it refers to: *grammar test*. Any other adjective (a past participle or an adjective proper) will come before that: *a written grammar test, a difficult grammar test.*

Comment: It's not a compound noun but a syntactic construction, more specifically a noun phrase consisting of "written" + grammar test", where the noun "grammar" modifies "test" to give the nominal "grammar test" which in turn is modified by the adjective "written". Note that "written" is not a verb here but an adjective.